# rails referenced object nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a one to one association between my quiz model and my quiz_session model, and when I try to access @quiz.quiz_session in the quiz controller, the quiz_session object is nil.
But when I check my quiz_session object in the rails console it shows a referenced quiz.

```
# quizzes_controller.rb:
def show
    @quiz_session = @quiz.quiz_session
    logger.debug "quizzes_controller"
    logger.debug @quiz_session.inspect
end

#development.log output:
quizzes_controller
nil

#quiz.rb:
class Quiz < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :quiz_session, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :quiz_session, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end

#quiz_session.rb:
class QuizSession < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :quiz
end

#rails console:
irb(main):001:0> QuizSession.first
  QuizSession Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "quiz_sessions".* FROM "quiz_sessions" ORDER BY "quiz_sessions"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<QuizSession id: 31, access_key: "srtjki356xm", created_at: "2017-04-23 22:54:51", updated_at: "2017-04-23 22:54:51", quiz_id: 1, current_question_index: nil>
irb(main):002:0> Quiz.find(1)
  Quiz Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "quizzes".* FROM "quizzes" WHERE "quizzes"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Quiz id: 1, title: "Chapter 1.1", lecture_unit: "2017-03-19", unlocked_at: "2017-03-19 14:00:00", course_id: 1, created_at: "2017-03-19 02:27:28", updated_at: "2017-03-19 02:27:28">
```

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and using Rails 5.0.2. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: what is `@quiz` for which you get `nil` for `quiz_session`?

Comment: add `@quiz = Quiz.find(1)` at the beginning of `show` method to check whether it is working for `quiz_id` 1

Comment: try `@quiz = Quiz.find(params[:id])`

Comment: I built the quiz controller with scaffolding, so (at)quiz is defined in the new method as (at)quiz = Quiz.new . (How do you do code formatting in comments? oO)

Comment: Under your Show method, how are you defining your @quiz variable? You can't pull `quiz_session` from a variable that you haven't defined. Defining it under the New method doesn't count. As sa77 said, you can pass the id of any `quiz` when you call show and assign it then.

Comment: ok, thanks. My quiz controller show method looks like this atm: (at)quiz = Quiz.find(params[:id])      logger.debug "quiz id in controller show method" 
    logger.debug (at)quiz.id     (at)quiz_session = (at)quiz.quiz_session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below:

```
# quizzes_controller.rb:
def show
    @quiz_session = @quiz.quiz_session
    logger.debug "quizzes_controller"
    logger.debug @quiz_session.inspect
end

#quiz.rb:
class Quiz < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :quiz_session, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :quiz_session, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
#quiz_session.rb:
class QuizSession < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :quiz
end
```

This is because your quiz_session contains quiz_id = 1. But this is not a good solution to hardcode the things. You should make logic to pass the quiz id from the request & then make the `@quiz = Quiz.find(params[:quiz_id])` dynamically. For now , you can use the above solution.

Comment: I did, but I get the same error: NoMethodError in Quizzes#show. Also: I don't want to connect all the quiz sessions to the quiz with id 1, but it was good for testing - thanks :)

Comment: since I can't edit my question here the development log: [link](https://pastebin.com/GJChK77C)

Comment: which part? where do I look?

Comment: You need to update the association as in aboce model, has_one & belongs_to are not properly placed

Comment: I can't find quiz_id = 1 in my code... my quiz controller show method currently lokks like this: (at)quiz = Quiz.find(params[:id])
    (at)quiz_session = (at)quiz.quiz_session

Comment: Try @quiz = Quiz.find(1) before quiz_session

Comment: ok, but flipping the associations, so quiz.rb has the has_one and quiz_session.rb has the belongs_to association means that I need to change the db as well - delete the quiz_id column from the quiz table and add a quiz_session_id to the quiz table.... isn't there another way that would allow me to keep the current db setup?

Comment: no, in quiz table , there should be a field id instead of quiz_id & quiz_session table contains quiz_id columns

Comment: You just need to flip the associations only

Comment: you're right! I changed quiz.rb to has_one and quiz_session.rb to belongs_to and it works! Thank you so much! :D